# Why is my string changing contents after leaving the for loop it is contained in

Tags: c, string, for-loop

I'm trying to create a program that takes in command line arguments to take in text and output it into another text file swapping out characters and replacing them with a different one based upon user input, but when I try to open the input file it is unable to open because the contents of the string changes after leaving the for loop. I did initialize the string before hand and later assigned the name of the input file from the command line and once the initial for loop

Command terminal:

```
./a.out --hi -+yo -i input.txt -o output.txt
Letters to replace with:
h
i

String(2): h i 
from[2]
Letters to be replaced:
y
o

String(2): y o 
input File Name:
i 
String(1): i 
n 
String(2): i n 
p 
String(3): i n p 
u 
String(4): i n p u 
t 
String(5): i n p u t 
. 
String(6): i n p u t . 
t 
String(7): i n p u t . t 
x 
String(14): i n p u t . t x � , � p � U 
t 
String(14): i n p u t . t x t , � p � U 
 
String(9): i n p u t . t x t 
String(9): i n p u t . t x t 

String(9): i n p u t . t x t 

String(6): 0 � � � �  

End of Program
```

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void help()
{
    printf("HELP TEXT\n\n");
}

void printString(char *string)
{
    //String Test
    printf("String(%ld): ", strlen(string));
    int p = 0;
    for (p = 0; p < strlen(string); p++)
    {
        printf("%c ", string[p]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i, toLen, fromLen;
    int fromChars = 0, toChars = 0, outArg = 0, inpArg = 0;
    char *to;
    char *from;
    FILE *fileInput;
    FILE *fileOutput;   
    char c;
    for (i = 0; i < argc; i++)
    {
        //Begin argument search
        int j;
        //printf("argv[%d]: %s\n", i, argv[i]);//Curren Argv
        for (j = 0; j < strlen(argv[i]); j++)
        {
            //Loop each arg starting with '-'
            //printf("char: %c\n", argv[i][j]);//Char of Argv[#]
            if (argv[i][j] == '-')
            {
                if (argv[i][j + 1] == 'h')
                {
                    //help trigger
                    printf("Help Prompt\n");
                    help();
                    return 0;
                }
                if ((argv[i][j + 1] == '-') && (fromChars != 1))
                {
                    //letters to replace trigger
                    printf("Letters to replace with:\n");
                    int k;
                    char fromCharString[strlen(argv[i])];
                    for (k = 2; k <= strlen(argv[i]); k++)
                    {
                        //Moves from current pos char to a separate string
                        printf("%c\n", argv[i][k]);
                        fromCharString[k - 2] = argv[i][k];
                    }
                    from = fromCharString;
                    printString(from);
                    fromLen = strlen(from);
                    printf("from[%ld]\n", strlen(from));
                    if (dupeCheck(fromCharString) == 1)
                    {
                        //Checks for duplicate letters
                        return 1;
                    }
                    fromChars = 1;  //Flag use of fromChars
                    j = strlen(argv[i]);    //Moves to next argument
                }
                else if ((argv[i][j + 1] == '-') && (fromChars == 1))
                {
                    printf("sub: ERROR - multiple \"--\" arguments detected\n");
                    return 1;
                }
                if ((argv[i][j + 1] == '+') && (toChars != 1))
                {
                    //letters to replace trigger
                    printf("Letters to be replaced:\n");
                    int k;
                    char toCharString[strlen(argv[i])];
                    for (k = 2; k <= strlen(argv[i]); k++)
                    {
                        printf("%c\n", argv[i][k]);
                        toCharString[k - 2] = argv[i][k];
                    }
                    to = toCharString;
                    printString(to);
                    toLen = strlen(to);
                    toChars = 1;
                    j = strlen(argv[i]);
                }
                else if ((argv[i][j + 1] == '+') && (toChars == 1))
                {
                    printf("sub: ERROR - multiple \"-+\" arguments detected\n");
                    return 1;
                }
                if ((argv[i][j + 1] == 'o') && (outArg != 1))
                {
                    i++;
                    //output file
                    //printf("Output File Name:\n");
                    int k;
                    char outputName[strlen(argv[i])];
                    for (k = 0; k <= strlen(argv[i]); k++)
                    {
                        //printf("%c \n", argv[i][k]);
                        outputName[k] = argv[i][k];
                        //printString(outputName);
                        
                    }
                    //printString(outputName);
                    printf("\n");
                    fileOutput = fopen(outputName, "w");
                    fclose(fileOutput);
                    if(fileOutput == NULL)
                    {
                        printf("sub: ERROR - output file \"%s\" could not be created\n",outputName);
                        return 1;
                    }
                    outArg = 1;
                    j = strlen(argv[i]);
                }
                else if ((argv[i][j + 1] == 'o') && (toChars == 1))
                {
                    printf("sub: ERROR - multiple output file arguments \n");
                    return 1;
                }
                if (((argv[i][j + 1] == 'i') && (outArg != 1)))
                {
                    i++;
                    //input file
                    printf("input File Name:\n");
                    int k;
                    char inputName[strlen(argv[i])];
                    for (k = 0; k <= strlen(argv[i]); k++)
                    {
                        printf("%c \n", argv[i][k]);
                        inputName[k] = argv[i][k];
                        printString(inputName);
                    }
                    printString(inputName);
                    printf("\n");
                    to = inputName;
                    printString(to);
                    fileInput = fopen(inputName, "r");
                    fclose(fileInput);
                    if(fileInput == NULL)
                    {
                        printf("sub: ERROR - invalid input file not found\n");
                        return 1;
                    }
                    inpArg = 1;
                    j = strlen(argv[i]);
                }
            }
        }
            if (fromChars == 1 && toChars == 1)
            {
                //printf("from length:%d \nto length:%d\n", fromLen, toLen);
                if (fromLen > toLen)
                {
                    printf("sub: ERROR - missing replacement character\n");
                    return 1;
                }
                else if (fromLen < toLen)
                {
                    printf("sub: WARNING - extraneous replacement character \n");
                }
            }
        if (outArg == 0)
        {
        //check if ther is an output name
            fileOutput = fopen("output.txt", "w");
        }
    }
    printString(to);
    printf("\nEnd of Program\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There are several `for` loops, which one are you talking about? Can you reduce this to a [mcve]?

Comment: It seems like your `for` loops are just duplicating what `strcpy()` does.

Comment: Why is your implementation of `printString` not simply `printf("%s\n", string);` ?

Comment: Why don't you use `getopts()` to process command line arguments, instead of this ad hoc parsing that you can't get right?

Comment: `char outputName[strlen(argv[i])];` is not big enough. You need to add 1 for the null terminator.

Comment: "I try to open the input file it is unable to open because the contents of the string changes after leaving the for loop." reads like multiple problems, not one. Especially not like one with a cause. Please reduce to a [mre] demonstrating one problem.

Comment: `Undefined reference to function dupeCheck()`

Comment: OT: regarding statements like: `int p = 0;
    for (p = 0; p < strlen(string); p++)`   The function `strlen()` returns a `size_t` not a `int`

Comment: the posted code causes the compiler to output 15 warnings, some of which are critical.  When compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  ( for `gcc`, at a minimum use the options: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )  Note: other compilers use different options to produce the same results

Comment: the posted output clearly shows that the code is not properly NUL terminating the strings

Comment: regarding: `for (i = 0; i < argc; i++)`  argv[0] is always the name of the program being executed.  YOU do NOT want to use `argv[0]` as part of the user/command line parameters

Answer (score 1):

It was difficult for me to read through the code. I tried to re-structure the code a bit using `enum` and `switch`-`case` and tried to eliminate some `for` loops by using inbuilt functions like `memset` and `memcpy` (you can also use `strncpy` instead). I think the arguments parsing works and I hope I have considered most of the scenarios.

Hope this helps a bit.

**NOTE**:

1. I haven't completed the code, many parts are remaining which are marked as `TODO` in the comments.
2. There was an `Undefined reference` to a function `dupeCheck()` in your code.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

void help()
{
    printf("HELP TEXT\n\n");
}

void printString(char *s)
{
    printf("String: %s [%d]\n", s, strlen(s));
}

enum TokenType
{
    INPUT_FILE,
    OUTPUT_FILE,
    CHARS_TO_REPLACE_WITH,
    CHARS_TO_BE_REPLACED,
    HELP,
    OPTION_VALUE,
    INVALID
};

// returns the type of token
enum TokenType getTokenType(const char* token)
{
    if (token == NULL)
        return INVALID;
    
    const int len = strlen(token);
    if (len >= 2)
    {
        switch (token[0])
        {
            // options
            case '-':
            {
                switch (token[1])
                {
                    case 'h':
                        if (len > 2)
                            return INVALID;
                        return HELP;
                    case '-':
                        if (len <= 2)
                            return INVALID;
                        return CHARS_TO_REPLACE_WITH;
                    case '+':
                        if (len <= 2)
                            return INVALID;
                        return CHARS_TO_BE_REPLACED;
                    case 'i':
                        if (len > 2)
                            return INVALID;
                        return INPUT_FILE;
                    case 'o':
                        if (len > 2)
                            return INVALID;
                        return OUTPUT_FILE;
                    default:
                        printf("Something went wrong: invalid token %s\n", token);
                        return INVALID;
                }
                break;
            }
            // option value (input, output files)
            default:
                return OPTION_VALUE;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return INVALID;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i, toLen, fromLen;
    int fromChars = 0, toChars = 0, outArg = 0, inpArg = 0;
    char *to = NULL;
    char *from = NULL;
    FILE *fileInput = NULL;
    FILE *fileOutput = NULL;
    char c;
    printf("No. of arguments: %d\n", argc);
    // flags to help track last read option
    bool is_input = false, is_output = false;
    for (i = 1; i < argc; i++)
    {
        const int len = strlen(argv[i]);
        enum TokenType type = getTokenType(argv[i]);
        //printf("%s %d\n", argv[i], type);
        switch (type)
        {
            case INVALID:
                printf("Something went wrong: invalid argument %s\n", argv[i]);
                exit(1);
            case INPUT_FILE:
                if (is_output || is_input)
                {
                    printf("Something went wrong: invalid argument %s\n", argv[i]);
                    exit(1);
                }
                is_input = true;
                break;
            case OUTPUT_FILE:
                if (is_output || is_input)
                {
                    printf("Something went wrong: invalid argument %s\n", argv[i]);
                    exit(1);
                }
                is_output = true;
                break;
            case CHARS_TO_BE_REPLACED:
                from = calloc(len + 1, sizeof(char));
                memset(from, 0, len + 1);
                memcpy(from, argv[i] + 2, len - 2);
                fromLen = len - 2;
                //printf("from: %s\n", from);
                
                //TODO: handle duplicates
                break;
            case CHARS_TO_REPLACE_WITH:
                to = calloc(len + 1, sizeof(char));
                memset(to, 0, len + 1);
                memcpy(to, argv[i] + 2, len - 2);
                toLen = len - 2;
                //printf("to: %s\n", to);
                
                //TODO: handle duplicates
                break;
            case HELP:
                if (is_output || is_input)
                {
                    printf("Something went wrong: invalid argument %s\n", argv[i]);
                    exit(1);
                }
                help();
                exit(0);
            case OPTION_VALUE:
                if (is_input)
                {
                    is_input = false;
                    fileInput = fopen(argv[i], "r");
                    if (!fileInput)
                    {
                        printf("Something went wrong: file couldn't be opened %s\n", argv[i]);
                        exit(1);
                    }
                }
                else if (is_output)
                {
                    is_output = false;
                    fileOutput = fopen(argv[i], "w+");
                    if (!fileOutput)
                    {
                        printf("Something went wrong: file couldn't be opened %s\n", argv[i]);
                        exit(1);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("Something went wrong: invalid argument %s\n", argv[i]);
                    exit(1);
                }
                break;
            default:
                exit(1);
        }
    }
    if (fromLen != toLen)
    {
        printf("From and To strings are different in length: from='%s' to='%s'\n", from, to);
        exit(1);
    }
    
    // TODO: read input file
    
    // close input file
    fclose(fileInput);
    
    // TODO: perform replacement
    
    // TODO: write to output file
    
    // close output file
    fflush(fileOutput);
    fclose(fileOutput);
    
    // cleanup
    free(from);
    free(to);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks I tried to remove any excess code that wasn't effecting memory. the dupeCheck() function was a function that checked within a string if there was a duplicate letter. It worked fine and probably could be more optimized but I was concerned with how my string was changing. 
I also didn't know enum was a thing an this is a much more neater solution as it enables the use of a switch statement, which I never thought was possible for something like this.

Answer (score 0):

regarding your question:

*Why is my string changing contents after leaving the for loop it is contained in*

Your returning a local variable character array, which means the array is on the stack.

The next call will overlay some portion of the stack, which corrupts the original array